# Javascript: Object to URL to Object

Tags: javascript, url

I have a Javascript object (or array of objects?) of the form:

```
   [{"id":"1","col":"0.35","type":"1"},{"id":"2","col":"0.30","type":"1"},{"id":"11","col":"0.20","type":"0"}]
```

I want to turn this into a URL and then be able to parse this URL back into the same form when the page loads. I would also like to add a title element to the front of the URL which would be stripped off before re-creating the object. So the URL for the above might look like: *(i don't need the keys as the urls could be long)*

http://example.com/myURL.html?Page_Title&1,0.35,1&2,0.30,1&11,0.20,0

Then when the page loads I'd remove 'Page_Title' and re-create the object, adding back in the id: , col: and type: keys).

The URL could potentially hold dozens of {id,col,type} groups.

I'm working with this function but I can't seem to get it working. I'm sure it's something simple that I've misunderstood or overlooked.

```
  function ArrayToURL(array,title) {
    var pairs = [];
     for (var key in array)
     if (array.hasOwnProperty(key))
     pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(array[key])); 
     my_title=(encodeURIComponent(title)); 
     return ("http://example.com/myURL.html?")+my_title+'&'+pairs.join('&'); 
    }
```

Comment: Why json data in URL ?

Comment: I'm storing settings in localStorage. The URL is being parsed from a stored localStorage string and will then eventually go back there. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
function ArrayToURL(array,title) {
var pairs = [];
for (var key in array){

var obj = array[key];
var temp='';

for(var key in obj){
    temp+=obj[key]+",";
}

pairs.push(temp); 

}

 my_title=(encodeURIComponent(title)); 

 return ("http://example.com/myURL.html?")+my_title+'&'+pairs.join('&'); 
}
```

Comment: This looks much better than mine. Could you give me an idea of how to convert this URL back into the object?